# To skip a row containing the searchstring in excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, row, skip

I have a loop for a spreadsheet which already has a bit of code in it. Basically in VBA what I want to do is:

`If x = Searchstring.row then GoTo continue` (which isn't defined)

I am currently using `If x = activecell.row GoTo continue`, but when I add information to a new row the old cell is updated which includes the searchstring row (since it is no longer the `ActiveCell.row`)

Below is the code I am using (sorry it is a bit messy):

```
Function RelLookup(ByVal Searchstring As String, Reldate As String, _
                SearchRange As Range, TicketRange As Range, ReldateRange As Range, _
                RelRange As Range, Optional UniqueOnly As Boolean = True)

Dim X As Long, Task As String, ReldateVal As String, TicketVal As String, ReturnRel As String, _
Result As String

For X = 1 To SearchRange.Count
If X = ActiveCell.row Then GoTo Continue


Task = SearchRange(X).Value
ReldateVal = ReldateRange(X).Value
TicketVal = TicketRange(X).Value
ReturnRel = RelRange(X).Value

If (Task = Searchstring) And (ReldateVal = Reldate) Then
Result = Result & " Rel " & ReturnRel & " (" & TicketVal & ")" & " &"
End If

Continue:
Next X

If Len(Result) > 0 Then RelLookup = Left(Result, Len(Result) - 2)


End Function
```

Comment: ... I don't understand what you mean by **"but when I add a new cell the old cell is updated which includes the searchstring row (since it is no longer the activecell.row)"** - When would a new cell be added? How would your issue arise??... Can you please explain the specific issue you're facing in a bit more detail?

Comment: Sorry the desc wasn't 100% clear and i meant "..when i add new row" The spreadsheet is updated every time there is a new release. The reason for the formula is to find releases which contain the same searchstring as the one used in the formula and since there are over 900 rows, 500 releases and 80 different tasks this can get time consuming. But for example the formula would output:

Rel 400 dependent on Rel 3##, Rel 400,Rel 5## etc.. and i would like it to ignore the 400 (because, of course, Rel 400 is obviously dependent on Rel 400).
Hope this gives a little more detail.

Comment: So, if I understand your question correctly (And I very well might not), what you mean my `ActiveCell` is, technically, the cell that contains `SearchString`? Otherwise, I'm still a bit confused here...

Comment: The active cell is the cell with the formula in but, since this is on the same row as the searchstring, activecell.row means it will ignore that row, but I need it to always ignore the row not just when it is active. (I thought activecell.row would work but it doesn't)

Comment: @JohnBustos if there is a way to locate the row that the search string is on, this will solve the problem. e.g. if my search string is in E952, row = 952 and so on.. would this be easier if it was a string of its own?

Comment: ... That's EXACTLY what I was thinking... Don't make the searchstring a `String` variable, make it a `Range` variable - Then pull the string from it and, at the same time, you have the ability to figure out where it is on the sheet... Does that make sense??

Comment: Also, if you specifically want to continue your other way (which I d o not recommend), look into `Application.Caller` ... check out this link that talks a bit about that: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I have found a work around that is fine for this case (Thanks for the help from @John Bustos). I have added an Integer called "RowNumber". I have then changed the VBA to read `If x = RowNumber GoTo Continue`
Although I now have a lengthy formula

```
=RelLookup(E955,Row(E955),"Not Rel",E:E,B:B,I:I,A:A,"")
```

The Integer RowNumber is determined by the value of Row(E955).

I will leave the question open in case there is an easier or more reliable way of doing this without introducing another string (although I cannot think of a more basic way around it)